# statistical analysis of a website offer

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance

I'm trying to assess the performance of an offer on a website. I divided recent buyers into two groups and gave one group a discount. Here are the revenues before discount & for 8 weeks after discount:

```
                        Control Group (10%)  Test Group (90%)
Daily Avg Before Offer  203                  1,851
Week1                   208                  2,502 
Week2                   205                  2,211 
Week3                   205                  1,723 
Week4                   197                  1,617 
Week5                   202                  1,596 
Week6                   202                  1,689 
Week7                   203                  1,839 
Week8                   204                  1,832
```

I'm thinking about conducting a t-test to assess statistical significance of the offer on the test group. Should I? In order to be able to compare revenue levels, I divided the revenues in the test group by 9. Does this make any sense? Would I need other data to assess statistical significance of this offer?

Comment: It definitely makes sense to divide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you will need to normalize the data to average spending per person (also stated in your question).

You can consider to use two samples t-test (or Welch t-test) for comparing between your control and treatment group. To do that, you should normalize your data. Consider this simplified example:

```
Before  10 9
Week1   12 10
Week2   13 8
```

You transform it to net-effect relative to the beginning of your experiment. Eg:

```
Week1  2 1
Week2  3 -1
```

If you now run t-test on your groups, you will be testing the net-effect of discount vs non-discount relative to the beginning of the experiment. Under the null hypothesis, your discount is worthless thus the net-effect for your second group should be close to your first group. If you can reject your null hypothesis, you can prove statistically that your discount has some non-random effects.

Comment: thank you, it helped me a lot! just one more question: my sample numbers are 8, because I'm comparing 8 weeks in each group. but what if I wanted to know whether the number of people involved in each group (90% and 10%) are enough? Let's say these revenue numbers are for 10 people. Then I'd be making conclusions based on the purchasing behaviour of just one person in the control group. How do I assess the total number of people (Control + Test) I should take into account?